# Is there any java library which can apply a visitor function to multiple elements of a pre-generics collection?

Tags: java, xpath, collections

I deal a lot with the pre-generics like Maps with Strings as the keys. They are mapping the keys to one of the following types of values:

- Another Map

  A List

  Primitives wrappers

You can access the collection content using either **XPath** or queries like that:

```
myMap/FIRST_LIST[2]/SECOND_LIST[1]/MY_MAP/MY_PRIMITIVE
```

What I am looking for is a library that would allow me to **apply a visitor function to the multiple elements of a collection**. The basic functionality could look like that

```
MyMapBrowser browser = new MyMapBrowser(myMap);
browser.applyVisitor("FIRST_LIST[*]/SECOND_LIST[*]/MY_MAP/MY_PRIMITIVE", 
  new AbstractVisitor<String>() {
    visit(String s) {
         // do something with the strings
    }
});
```

It would be also wonderful to have a possibility to **first register multiple visitors for various levels of collection and then start the visiting iteration**. It could look like this:

```
browser.registerVisitor(SECOND_LIST, new AbstractVisitor<MyList> { ... )
browser.doVisiting("FIRST_LIST[*]/SECOND_LIST[*]/MY_MAP/MY_PRIMITIVE");
```

In fact I've already started implementing a browser like that but I can't get rid of an impression that I'm reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: @ControlAltDel I would gladly know what exactly is unclear for you. I deal with the nested collections. At every level you can have either a list, a map or a primitive. I am able to query them using explicit indices for the lists - All I want is to use stars or indices range when I query for the multiple list elements. In addition I want to apply a functions (like in the functional programming) to the found elements.

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted this. Good question! I don't have an answer though and I think you tried google yourself. I'm not sure if you will find something though, this seems too specific to me (the nested Maps thing especially) - maybe a visitor implementation could aide somewhat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/)?  It lets you use XPath expressions to query and manipulate Java object graphs.  The [`JXPathContext`](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jxpath/JXPathContext.html) class lets you iterate over the values of selected nodes if you just want to extract the string values, or you can use the `selectNodes` method to get JDOM wrappers.

For instance, I *think* your example query would look something like:

```
// untested
JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(myMap);
Iterator iter = context.iterate("FIRST_LIST/SECOND_LIST/MY_MAP/MY_PRIMITIVE");
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String str = (String) iter.next();
    // do something with strings
}
```

Unfortunately I haven't actually worked with JXPath (though I've also tried implementing an XPath-like traverser before too), but apparently you can also configure it to automatically create objects for a particular path.  I didn't see any visitor functionality, but the `iterate`, `getValue`, and `setValue` should be able to accomplish the same thing.  You could also rig up a simple wrapper class to run the query, iterate through the nodes, and pass the values to your own visitor interface.  Something like:

```
public class JXPathVisitBrowser {
    private JXPathContext context;
    public JXPathVisitBrowser(Object object) {
        context = JXPathContext.newContext(object);
    }
    public <T> void applyVisitor(String query, AbstractVisitor<T> visitor) {
        Iterator iter = context.iterate(query);
        while (iter.hasNext())
            visitor.visit((T) iter.next());
    }
}
```

There's a pretty detailed [JXPath user guide](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/users-guide.html) too.

Comment: That's pretty much what I needed - brief and clear syntax with no overcomplexity. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/). I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was already aware of LambdaJ but I read more and I've found some info about so called  [extensibility features](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajExtensibility) ) You have there a Converter which is similar to Visitor. In addition it allows you to define a Matcher which could find elements according to the query string. However the converter requires a flat collection as an input - so the multilevel triggering would be hard. Moreover all that would need a lot of coding - I hoped maybe for a XPath based solution which won't require writing my own parser.